# Using SVD to reconstruct left and right singular vectors of low-rank matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

Given a $ n \times m $ matrix $ \mathbf{A}$ whose rank I know is $r \ll n,m$, i.e.,

$$ \mathbf{A} = \sum_{i=1}^r \mathbf{a}_i \mathbf{b}_i^T $$

I would like to reconstruct the unknown column and row vectors $\mathbf{a}_i$ and $\mathbf{b}_i$ for $i > r$.

If I use the SVD to compute the low-rank approximation of $ \mathbf{A} $ all but the first $r$ singular values will be zero, and the following will hold:

$$ \mathbf{A} = \sum_{i=1}^r \mathbf{u}_i s_i \mathbf{v}_i^T  = \sum_{i=1}^r \mathbf{a}_i \mathbf{b}_i^T $$

where $\mathbf{u}_i$ and $\mathbf{v}_i$ are the left and right singular vectors respectively and $s_i$ are the corresponding singular values. Yet the $\mathbf{u}_i$ will not directly correspond to the input vectors $\mathbf{a}_i$.

Is there a relationship of the sort $ \mathbf{a}_i = f( \mathbf{u}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{u}_r)$ that would allow me to set up an optimization problem for the reconstruction of the unknown $\mathbf{a}_i$ and $\mathbf{b}_i$?

All tips on how to approach this problem or literature references would be appreciated!

Comment: You are using the "economy" SVD. Why not use the full SVD?

Comment: There is no specific reason. I haven't put any thought into that. Would it make a difference?

Comment: Full SVD produces an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb R^m$ and an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb R^n$, which is what you want. Economy SVD produces an orthonormal basis for the column space and an orthonormal basis for the row space. You want more. You also want an orthonormal basis for the left null space and an orthonormal basis for the right null space.

Comment: Let me call your matrix $M$ because I would like to define the matrices $A=[a_1,\dots,a_r]$, $U=[u_1,\dots,u_r]$, and so on. We have $M=AB^T=USV^T$. Then (I'm pretty sure that) any $A$ is of the form $UP$ for some invertible $r\times r$ matrix $P$, with the corresponding $B$ being determined by $B^T=P^{-1}SV^T$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Thank you for your input, but I'm afraid I don't get your point. If I'm only interrested in the reconstruction of $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$: why should I be interrested in the basis of the null spaces when I already know that the unknown vectors make up the column and row space? I'm sorry if I'm missing an obvious point here, but I'm not a trained mathematician...

Comment: @Rahul: This is exactly what I was hoping for. I just ran a numerical test and it worked perfectly for the example I chose. But can I be sure that $\mathbf{A}$ will always be a linear transformation of $\mathbf{U}$? Do you happen to know a citable reference?

Comment: Just do a full SVD. $$\mathrm A = \mathrm U \Sigma \mathrm V^{\top} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm U_1 & \mathrm U_2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_1 & \mathrm O\\ \mathrm O & \mathrm O\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm V_1^{\top}\\ \mathrm V_2^{\top}\end{bmatrix} =  \mathrm U_1 \Sigma_1 \mathrm V_1^{\top}$$ You have matrices $\rm U_1$, $\Sigma_1$ and $\rm V_1$ already. You want $\rm U_2$ and $\rm V_2$.

Comment: No. I am trying to reconstruct $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ from $\mathbf{U}_1$ and $\mathbf{V}_1$. But $\mathbf{U}_1$ will not necessarily correspond to the original vectors $[\mathbf{a}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{a}_r]$. The question is what is the relationship between $[\mathbf{a}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{a}_r]$ and  $\mathbf{U}_1$  if $\mathbf{A} = \sum_{i=1}^r \mathbf{a}_i \mathbf{b}_i^T$? Or: Can I be sure that $[\mathbf{a}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{a}_r]$ will be a linear transformation of $\mathbf{U}_1$?